# How can I impute the NA in a dataframe with values randomly selected from a specified normal distribution

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

How can I impute the NA in a dataframe with values randomly selected from a specified normal distribution.
The dataframe df is defined as follows:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   3   NA  4   NA
2   3.4 2.3 4.1 NA
3   2.3 0.1 0.2 6.3
4   3.1 4.5 2.1 0.2
5   4.1 2.5 NA  2.4
```

I want to fill the NA with the values randomly select from a generated normal distribution and the values are different.
The mean the normal distribution is the 1% quantile of the values of the given dataframe. The standard deviation is the median SD of the rows in dataframe.

My code is as follows:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('try.txt',sep="\t")
df.index = df['type']
del df['type']
sigma = median(df.std(axis=1))
mu = df.quantile(0.01)
# mean and standard deviation
df = df.fillna(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1))
```

The mean is incorrect and the df can not fill with the simulated array.
How can I complete the work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code

```
df.index = df['type']
del df['type']
```

can better be expressed as `df.set_index('type')`

`median(df.std(axis=1))` should be `df.std(axis=1).median()`

`df.quantile()` returns a series. If you want the quantile of all the values, you should do `df.stack().quantile(0.01)`

```
sigma = df.std(axis=1).median()
mu = df.stack().quantile(0.01)
print((sigma, mu))
```

> ```
>  (0.9539392014169454, 0.115)
> ```

First you have to find the empty fields. Easiest is with `.stack` and `pd.isnull`

```
df2 = df.stack(dropna=False)
s = df2[pd.isnull(df2)]
```

Now you can impute the random values in 2 ways

```
ran = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(s))
df3 = df.stack(dropna=False)
df3.loc[s.index] = ran
df3.unstack()
```

> ```
>   A   B   C   D
> 1 3.0 0.38531116198179066 4.0 0.7070154252582993
> 2 3.4 2.3 4.1 -0.8651789931843614
> 3 2.3 0.1 0.2 6.3
> 4 3.1 4.5 2.1 0.2
> 5 4.1 2.5 -1.3176599584973157 2.4
> ```

Or via a loop, overwriting the empty fields in the original `DataFrame`

```
for (row, column), value in zip(s.index.tolist(), np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(s))):
    df.loc[row, column] = value
```